# Specflow SpecRun doesn't find my test cases

Tags: c#, specflow, specrun

So I can successfully run my Specflow test cases from Visual Studio or from Rider, but when I would like to do it from a command line with SpecRun it recognises 0 test cases.

After executing SpecRun.exe/runtests.bat I get the following output:

```
Discovered 0 tests
Thread#0:

Done.
Result: tests executed with warnings
  Total: 0
```

I am using the latest stable NuGet packages for SpecFlow and SpecRun.

I have no idea what can be the problem, maybe anybody knows a debugging option? Is there any rule where should be the feature files?

Comment: Are you able to see the the Tests in the Visual Studio Test Explorer?

Comment: Yes I can see it. But not in SpecRun

Comment: I have the same issue, v frustrating

Comment: Was there any update on this? I am going through this right now, and feel downright incompetent because I cannot get specrun to run from the command line. VS is all ok, only command line.

There needs to be a correction to their documentation, btw."projectID" is not acceptable in the Settings file. It must be "projectId". Setting names are case sensitive.